# Android Bluetooth LE - Read float characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt

I am trying to read the float characteristic of a connected Bluetooth LE device(Genuino 101). For testing purposes, the device provides a FloatCharacteristic with the hardcoded Value '55.3'. While I am able to receive a string that somehow resembles the float, I cannot read an actual float value.
Here's the code fragment that handles a string:

```
// For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
            for(byte byteChar : data)
                stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
        }
```

this is copied straight from the https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html BLE demo project from the android developer homepage.
The intent is then handled by this snippet:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Broadcast received");
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {

        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {

        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
           displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
        }
    }
};

private void displayData(String data) {
    if (data != null) {
        System.out.println("Data Received: " + data);
    }
}
```

Which leads to the output

```
I/System.out: Data Received: 33]B 
I/System.out: 33 33 5D 42
```

So, set aside the swapped endianness, this is the correct hex value for 55.3f.
However, if I try to use characteristic.getFloatValue(), I only get garbage. Here's how I tried figuring out how to receive an actual float:

```
final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i< 333; i++) {
                try {
                    final float fData = characteristic.getFloatValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_FLOAT, i);
                    System.out.println("Offset = "+ i + ". Data that gets sent: " + fData + "/Data that we would expect: " + 55.3f);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception at offset " + i);
                }
            }
        }
```

the output is always

```
I/System.out: Offset = 0. Data that gets sent: Infinity/Data that we would expect: 55.3
I/System.out: Exception at offset 1
I/System.out: Exception at offset 2
...
```

What is my mistake here? Also, I'm not sure how the Offset parameter should be understood. Is it the offset in bit, in byte? Counting from MSB, from LSB?
Also the documentation of getFloatValue() claims "returns float - Cached value of the characteristic at a given offset or null if the requested offset exceeds the value size. ". But the above snippet grossly exceeds the maximum size of any gatt characteristic, yet instead of returning 'null', the method call throws exceptions.
So what's the correct way to get a float here?

Comment: For the time being, I helped myself by formatting the data with `float f1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();` although this is a 'quick&dirty hack' and I'd rather use the dedicated getFloatValue() method.

Comment: And if you try to parse one byte to int ?

Comment: You are looping over i, but you will get the same value for each loop because the offset in characteristic.getFloatValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_FLOAT, 0) is always set to 0. Try to set it to "i" instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, @Nebr , this mistake indeed slipped through. It didn't solve my problem though, I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Daniel , not sure what you're suggesting there. You mean with BluetoothGattCharacteristic.getIntValue() method? That'd sound like an even worse hack.

Comment: I am not sure how endianness might affect this problem, especially which endianness is used for getFloatValue. You assume 33 33 5D 42 to be Little Endian (DCBA), but if the function uses Mid-Little-Endian (CDAB) the value would be 874599033891455000 which might very well be interpreted as infinity. Unfortunately, I could not find a specification of getFloatValue that is detailed enough to answer the question of endianness for this function. You can test endianness if you take 00 01 02 03 instead and check which value is returned.

Comment: No , when you recive data of Bel device you have a byte[] array , suggest you take element by element and covert o int or string to see the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time being, I helped myself by formatting the data with

```
 float f1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloa‌​t();
```

.